# Ho to transfer SPL-tokens (NFT) to another wallet using Phantom?

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, spl-token, nft, phantom

I'm working on project where i need to transfer NFT's or tokens from connected wallet with Phantom or Solflare. So idk how to create `token account` (if it doesn't exist) and include it in `createTransferCheckedInstruction`.

I need to do it all in one transaction and sign it with Phantom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question. Here are the `params` args:

```
 * @param connection     Connection to use
 * @param payer          Payer of the transaction fees
 * @param source         Source account
 * @param mint           Mint for the account
 * @param destination    Destination account
 * @param owner          Owner of the source account
 * @param amount         Number of tokens to transfer
 * @param decimals       Number of decimals in transfer amount
 * @param multiSigners   Signing accounts if `owner` is a multisig
 * @param confirmOptions Options for confirming the transaction
 * @param programId      SPL Token program account
```

Sounds like you need help figuring out how to create the `destination` account. This account is a token account that will be:

- owned by the SPL token program,
- have an authority that is user you are sending to, and
- be for the token mint of the token you are sending

To initialize the account before sending, you should use `getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount`  or `createAssociatedTokenAccountIdempotent` like so:

```
const destination = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
   connection,
   payer, // presumably your wallet
   mint,  // of the token you are sending
   owner, // person you are sending the token to
)
```

This [guide](https://www.quicknode.com/guides/solana-development/spl-tokens/how-to-transfer-spl-tokens-on-solana) may be useful to learn a little more about how token transfers work and see a full example.

Comment: Thanks. By the way param payer should be window.solana if i connected with Phatnom or it should be just publickey(adress) ? 

And if the account doesn't exist, in order to create it you have to do the transaction first for create or it receiving with RPC? Cause I need to transfer so many NFT's from one account to another in one transaction

Comment: You might try the [Solana wallet adapter](https://github.com/anza-xyz/wallet-adapter) instead of just Phantom Connect. And then I'd probably look at assembling transactions using the helper functions that return instructions (and then adding them together), e.g.: 
- `createAssociatedTokenAccountIdempotentInstruction`
- `createTransferCheckedInstruction`

These will return `TransactionInstruction` objects that you can do something like: 

```js
        const transaction = new Transaction().add(ix1,ix2, ...);
        const signature = await sendTransaction(transaction, connection);
```

Comment: Thanks. It's smart. But in the **createAssociatedTokenAccountIdempotentInstruction** i need the param **associatedToken**. Ignore him? Or it will be created during the execution of the instruction? And then, as far as I understand, in the **createTransferCheckedInstruction** add this 'associatedToken' or the instruction itself?